# Как добавить класс при клике на чистом JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript

Как добавить, допустим, элементу с классом "main" класс "main--main-bg" при клике на элемент с классом "intro__btn"? И чтобы при клике на другой элемент с классом "intro__btn" класс "main--main-bg" удалялся у элемента с классом "main" и присваивался другой, указанный класс. Сам в JS не очень шарю, а в интернете готового не нашел на чистом JS, а ради этого загружать целый jQuery не хочется, т.к. глупо.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот так

```js
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName('intro__btn');
var par = document.getElementsByClassName('main');
btns[0].onclick = function() {
  par[0].classList.add("main--main-bg");
}
btns[1].onclick = function() {
  par[0].classList.remove("main--main-bg");
}
```

```css
.main {
  color: red;
}

.main--main-bg {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<p class="main">TEXT</p>
<button class="intro__btn">Добавить класс</button>
<button class="intro__btn">Удалить класс</button>
```

Comment: А массивы нужны для выбора элемента из класса иначе вернет undefined

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все работает. Но можете, пожалуйста, еще немного помочь?) Дело в том, что там 3 класса, нужно при клике на определенную кнопку, добавлять определенный класс. У меня, вроде, это сделать получилось. Но вот удаление - нет =) Получилось сделать удаление определенного класса лишь при нажатии на кнопку, которая его добавила. https://codepen.io/SilencerWeb/pen/rmvKym?editors=1100

Comment: Вам нужна чтобы кнопка и удаляла и добавляла класс? или как?

Comment: Да, я представляю это так: например, нажатие на кнопку "intro__btn--main", происходит удаление всех классов, кроме "main" и присваивается определенный...

Comment: Если бы вы не использовали pug я бы помог

Comment: Блин, а в чем проблема?

Comment: Я в нем не разбираюсь, но я постараюсь.

Comment: А понятно, добавьте комментарии в Javascript чтобы понять что к чему.

Comment: так там можно же посмотреть скомпилированый код =) http://prntscr.com/f7cy0y

Comment: У меня не работает! пишет: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined at scripts.js:3`.